# Sound output is being heard from microphone

Tags: sound, microphone, audio-jack

My issue is that when I plug in a microphone it acts like a speaker rather than as a microphone, and I can hear sound that the computer makes through it.

I have an HP 255 G5 laptop running Ubuntu 16.04, it has one combined connector for both headphone out and microphone in.

Comment: Do you mean that sound is being the music being played is showing as being input by the microphone? Also, how many rings are there on the microphone connector?

Comment: The HP 255 series comes with a single output/input connector, similar to the ones you find in phones or tablets, therefore you need an Y adapter. And, obviously, this has nothing to do with Ubuntu.

Comment: @MichaelBay Windows 7 can, using Realtek Audio Manager, distinguish input and output or, to be precise, I can select that plugged device is input - microphone.

Comment: @jrtapsell No, microphone is behaving like speaker. It has 6.3mm jack but I added 6.3mm to 3.5mm adapter.

Comment: You can't do that with the Linux driver. And that you can doesn't mean you should...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments, it seems your 3.5mm to 6.3mm adapter is connecting one of the output rings to the mic, if you put a combo to two 3.5mm adapter in between it should fix the issue.

[Example](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/like/272543438348)

Comment: Pardon, added 3.5mm to 6.3mm, otherwise I coudn't plug in.

Comment: I was suggesting an adapter like the one I linked, between the computer and the  3.5-6.3 adapter, so it only has the microphone rings, not all 4 rings in the combo socket