# Sound not working properly using headphone jack

Tags: sound

I'm rocking ubuntu 16.04 LTS on my laptop (alongside windows 10) and, 50% of the times I connect any headphone, the sound comes out weird; By weird I mean I can barely hear anything but high pitches and it's very distorted.

I know for a fact that all my headphones work correctly and, using windows, the sound works well 100% of the times, but using ubuntu sometimes works, sometimes doesn't.

If I remove the headphones, the sound in the speakers is always normal.
Also when using an external sound card, I've never experienced this issue, therefor I assume the problem is about the jack output.

Update:

`amixer` output:

```
Simple mixer control 'IEC958',0
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [on]
Simple mixer control 'IEC958',1
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [on]
Simple mixer control 'IEC958',2
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [on]
```

`sudo lshw -C sound`output:

```
 *-multimedia:0          
       description: Audio device
       product: Broadwell-U Audio Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:03.0
       version: 09
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
       resources: irq:52 memory:9b31c000-9b31ffff
  *-usb:0
       description: Video
       product: USB Camera
       vendor: 04081-00092400F9FM47
       physical id: 5
       bus info: usb@1:5
       version: 0.12
       serial: 200901010001
       capabilities: usb-2.00
       configuration: driver=uvcvideo maxpower=500mA speed=480Mbit/s
  *-multimedia:1
       description: Audio device
       product: Wildcat Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1b
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1b.0
       version: 03
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=32
       resources: irq:51 memory:9b318000-9b31bfff
```

[Alsamixer bars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8kSiz.png)

Comment: Is your laptop connector a combo jack(mic + headphones), and how many rings do your headphones have?

Comment: @jrtapsell Yes, it's a combo jack and my headphones have 3 rings

Comment: Do you have a pair of headphones/earphones with 4 rings (with a mic), if so could you test with them, just to rule out a set of issues quickly? I just want to rule out an issue that is similar to this one: https://askubuntu.com/questions/952351/sound-output-is-being-heard-from-microphone

Comment: @jrtapsell yes I do

Comment: Could you test with them and see if the sound works please

Comment: It doesn't either

Comment: Can you try running `alsamixer` and see if any of the bars are set too high or too low

Comment: I'm not sure where are the bars you said, but running alsamix, gives me info about Card, Chip, View, Item and there are 3 squares in the middle S/PDIF, S/PDIF 1 and S/PDIF 2

Comment: Ricardo, paste output of this command `amixer` and `sudo lshw -C sound` into your question, not here, because comments are get longer. In alsamixer, press F6 to switch audio device. Normally HDMI devices doesn't show bars @jrtapsell mentioned.

Comment: @Redbob Alright, the question is updated with both outputs and a printscreen from alsamixer bars